# Why aren't my animation pseudo-elements working with an input element?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, pseudo-element

I'm trying to emulate the button shown here: https://codepen.io/nw/pen/udkIB

I am trying to add my animation in the value button, but it's not working. The download arrow shape & download nox shape are not showing.

Here is my code:

```css
.buttonDownload {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background-color: #4CC713;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 15px;
}

.buttonDownload:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

.buttonDownload:before,
.buttonDownload:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 52%;
}


/* Download box shape  */

.buttonDownload:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px;
}


/* Download arrow shape */

.buttonDownload:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-top: -7px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px 4px 0 4px;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: inherit;
  -webkit-animation: downloadArrow 2s linear infinite;
  animation: downloadArrow 2s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.buttonDownload:hover:before {
  border-color: #4CC713;
}

.buttonDownload:hover:after {
  border-top-color: #4CC713;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
  animation-play-state: running;
}


/* keyframes for the download icon anim */

@-webkit-keyframes downloadArrow {
  /* 0% and 0.001% keyframes used as a hackish way of having the button frozen on a nice looking frame by default */
  0% {
    margin-top: -7px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  0.001% {
    margin-top: -15px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes downloadArrow {
  /* 0% and 0.001% keyframes used as a hackish way of having the button frozen on a nice looking frame by default */
  0% {
    margin-top: -7px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  0.001% {
    margin-top: -15px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Download" class="buttonDownload">
</form>
```

Comment: Your form-action is invalid. Absolute `action=""` URIs must start with `https://` `http://`, or `//`.

Comment: Why not just use the working code from the CodePen you're trying to emulate?

Answer (score 5):

Pseudo-elements like `:before` and `:after` don't work on any `<input>` elements. In your linked example it works, because it uses a `<a>`

So you will have to replace this HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Download" class="buttonDownload">
```

with this:

```
<button type="submit" class="buttonDownload">Download</button>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fL2e6t8o/